# React toastify : Prevent displaying duplicate Toast

Tags: react-toastify

How can i prevent displaying duplicates toast in react-toastify.
I have setTimeout function that call an api every 5 seconds when token expired ,It's return  expired token in toast.err. I wanna to not display a lot of toast for every call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to provide a custom id to your toasts if id will remain same it wont duplicate.

[Reference](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/prevent-duplicate)